# Gradient Descent - Working on python one liner for residual function

Tags: python-2.7

looking to clean up my code. Currently going through a coursera course on machine learning. Having an issue shortening up my code:

```
class LRGD():

    def __init__(self, theta, x, y):
        self.theta = theta
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.l = len(y)
        self.lt = len(theta)

    def residual(self):
        sum = 0
        for j in range(self.l):
            # h = 0
            h = sum(self.theta[k] * self.x[k][j] for k in range(self.lt))
            # for k in range(self.lt):
            #     h += self.theta[k] * self.x[k][j]
            sum += (h-self.y[j])**2
        return sum/self.l
```

The 'residual' function works properly but I am working on shortening, hopefully close to a one liner.. can't figure out why the not commented out h isn't working -> the error thrown is 'int' is not callable.

Answer (score 2):

You override the built-in `sum` function with a local variable:

```
def residual(self):
    sum = 0  # this overshaddows the built-in sum function
    for j in range(self.l):
        h = sum( ... )  # "sum" here is the variable, not the function
        ...
```

Just use a different variable name, e.g. `total = 0`.